# What is the synonym phrase we could use instead of “si tratti”?

Tags: verbs

I was reading a sentence as:

> ...La polizia sospetta si tratti un gruppo di persone...

How could this sentence be rephrased? Is *si tratti* a formal phrase? If I am right, is there a spoken way for it?

The reason I think so is I usually read this kind of verb but haven't heard it in dialogues.

Comment: FabioSpaghetti, I took the liberty of partially rewriting your question to make it more readable. In particular, note that you say *un gruppo di persone*, not *un gruppo delle persone*.

Comment: that's the conjunctive tense of the verb "trattare" with an impersonal use.
I think that the phrase is not completely correct. The correct form should be:
"La polizia sospetta (che) si tratti di un gruppo di persone..."

The verb "Trattare" is used here with the meaning of "to be a question (of)"; "to be a matter (of)"; to have to do (with)

see http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/trattare/ point 4.

Comment: Ok thank you Riccardo, so how would you rephrase it?

Comment: I mean using another verb instead of trattare

Comment: The full sentence could help to find a good alternative; but you could as well use the verb "to be":
"La polizia sospetta che (ci) sia un gruppo di persone..."

If you prefer, you could use the expression "to have to do (with)":

"La polizia sospetta di avere a che fare con un gruppo di persone..."

Comment: Thank you very much, that was what I was searching for, I think the rest of the sentence was not a great help,  but your answer was complete thank you

Comment: I will add an answer based on my previous comments

Answer (score 1):

That phrase uses in an impersonal way the subjunctive mood of the verb "trattare"; but I think that the phrase is not completely correct. 
The correct phrase should be:

> La polizia sospetta (che) si tratti **di** un gruppo di persone...

(The conjunction "che" can be omitted).

The verb "*trattare*" is used here with the meaning of "*to be a question (of)*"; "*to be a matter (of)*"; "*to have to do (with)*" see treccani.it/vocabolario/trattare point 4

The full sentence could help to find a good alternative, but you could as well use the verb *essere* ("to be"):

> La polizia sospetta che (ci) sia un gruppo di persone...

If you prefer, you could use the expression to "*to have to do (with)*":

> La polizia sospetta di avere a che fare con un gruppo di persone...

I would not recommend this expression, especially for writing, because it is a bit too verbose. I think that even the usage of "trattare" would be discouraged for example on a newspaper article.

Answer (score -1):

...La polizia sospetta che un gruppo di persone sia coinvolto...

...La polizia sospetta che un gruppo di persone sia responsabile...